Teradata equivalent for calling a stored procedure and inserting results into a temp table?
I am new to Teradata and I am experiencing issues trying to insert data from a stored procedure into a temp table.
The SQL I would normally use:
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
(
   COL1 INT,
   COL2 INT
   ......
)

INSERT INTO #tmpTable
    EXEC SpGetResults @Params1 = 1 ...

What I have tried:
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
(
   COL1 INT,
   COL2 INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpTable
    CALL SpGetResults (1)

However, I am getting issues with syntax error mentioning it is incorrect. I tried looking online but could not find anything.

This syntax is not supported in Teradata (SPs can return multiple result sets).
Simply insert the result into a Global Temporary Table within the SP. I always recommend to save results in GTTs, as you can't join, aggregate, etc. the result returned by an SP. Of course, you can return it, too.
